# Inheritance and polymorphism using abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an abstract type `A`, and two derived types `A1` and `A2`.
I want to add a method M to class A, which takes a parameter of type A. But, I need ad hoc polymorphism.

Indeed, I need 3 implementations : `A1::M(A1 a)`, `A1::M(A2 a)` and `A2::(A1 a)`, `A2::M(A2 a)`.
But I want an abstract way to call the method M with pointers of type A.

I could put all signatures declaration in class `A`, but it sucks.

Comment: If you want to do this through pointers of type `A`, you don't have a lot of choice but to put `virtual M(A1)` and `virtual M(A2)` in the base class.

Comment: And the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) cannot be leveraged in any way (i.e. let double dispatch take place and the child members provide the actual implementation)?

Comment: I don't absolutly want to use a pointer of type A, i want an abstract interface to access objetcs A1 and A2, but i don't know how to do without pointers of type A. The visitor pattern seems good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is double dispatch.  When you write:

```
A* p1;
A* p2;
p1->M(*p2);
```

should dispatch both on the type of `*p1` and the type of `*p2`.

Before starting, you must realize that this means `n^2` functions for
`n` different derived types.  And that somewhere, someone must be aware
of all of the derived types (unless you can define some sort of
"default" implemenation for an unknown pair of types).

There are two ways of implementing this.  The simplest, if the hierarchy
is closed (i.e. client code cannot introduce new derived classes) does
use a host of virtual functions in the base class—generally
protected, since they're not designed to be called outside the
hierarchy:

```
//  Forward references needed for all derived classes...
class A1;
class A2;
//  ...

class A
{
protectd:
    virtual void doM(A1* arg) = 0;
    virtual void doM(A2* arg) = 0;
    //  ...

public:
    virtual void M(A& arg) = 0;
};
```

In the derived classes, the implementation of `M` is always the same:

```
void A1::M(A& arg)
{
    arg.doM( this );
}
```

This is simple, and relatively efficient, but requires changes in the
abstract base *and* all of the derived classes (which have to implement
the new virtual function) each time you add a new derived class.  It's
useful for closed hierarchies, however; I've used it in classes using
the strategy pattern for part of their behavior, where the various
strategies were all defined in the source file, and not exposed to the
clients (and the abstract base of the strategies was only forward
declared in the header, so no header changes were necessary if I added a
strategy).

A more general solution would involve an `std::map`, with a pair of
`typeid` as index.  You can't use `typeid` directly, since it's not
copyable.  C++11 provides a `type_index` to wrap it; if you're using an
older compiler, it's fairly trivial to implement one yourself.  The
basic principle is something along the lines of (probably in A itself):

```
typedef std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index> TypePairKey;
typedef void (*FuncPtr)( M* arg1, M* arg2 );
typedef std::unordered_map<TypePairKey, FuncPtr> DispatchMap;

static DispatchMap ourDispatchMap;
```

with:

```
void M( A& arg )        //  NOT virtual !!!
{
    DispatchMap::iterator entry
        = ourDispatchMap.find(
                DispatchMap::value_type( typeid( *this ), typeid( arg ) ) );
    assert( entry != ourDispatchMap.end() );
        //  Or some default handling, maybe throw NotYetImplemented()
    (*entry->second)( this, &arg );
}
```

The real problem comes with writing each of the individual functions and
inserting their addresses in the map (before first use).  The functions
themselves, of course, can use `dynamic_cast`, or even `static_cast`, if
you can be sure that they will only be called from here, and they can be
friend(s) of the class(es) involved, but there are still
*n<sup>2</sup>* of them.  (One frequent solution is to make them
static members of one of the classes, and to have each derived class
define a static member of a type which does the registration of all of
the functions its responsible for.)

Comment: Thank you for your long answer. The hierarchy being closed and having only 2 different subtypes, I think I can use your first method whithout inconvenient. And I can provide a default implementation, altougth it's unefficient : the combinatory here is used to speed up computation in particular cases. Adding more subtypes is just a matter of internal refactoring, even if modifying all the subclass is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Use [simulated double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B).

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void M(A &) = 0;
    virtual void M(A1 &) = 0;
    virtual void M(A2 &) = 0;
};

class A1 : public A {
public:
    virtual void M(A &a) { a.M(*this); }
    virtual void M(A1 &a) { std::cout << "A1 <- A1\n"; }
    virtual void M(A2 &a) { std::cout << "A2 <- A1\n"; }
};

class A2 : public A {
public:
    virtual void M(A &a) { a.M(*this); }
    virtual void M(A1 &a) { std::cout << "A1 <- A2\n"; }
    virtual void M(A2 &a) { std::cout << "A2 <- A2\n"; }
};
```

(See e.g. http://ideone.com/nycls.)

I don't think there is a way of avoiding the multiple overloads in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want polymorphic behavior - then all you need is one method in Base class A. You can then reimplement that method in A1, A2.

After that you can write:

```
A *a1 = new A1();
A *a2 = new A2();

a1->M(a2); //polymorphic behavior
```

If you make something like this:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void M(A *a) {}
};

struct A1 : public A
{
    virtual void M(A1 *a) {cout << "A1" << endl;}
    virtual void M(A *a) {cout << "A" << endl;}
};
```

Then:

```
A1 * a1 = new A1();
a1->M(a1); //prints "A1"
A  * a = a1;
a->M(a1); //prints "A"
```

I don't think this the behavior you want

Comment: I want polymorphic behavior in parameter too, and i don't see how i can re-implement a single virtual method declared in base class A, since i can't reimplement methods with another signature

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like that?

```
void A1::M( A a )
{
    if( dynamic_cast< A1* >( &a ) )
    {
        // do your A1::M1(A1 a) stuff
    }
    else
    if( dynamic_cast< A2* >( &a ) )
    {
        // do your A1::M2(A2 a) stuff
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::logic_error( "Unsupported A type." );
    }
}
```

And do equivalently for A2::M?

Comment: You're right, but I may not use dynamic_cast. And, even if it will work as needed, i think it's a poor design. Anyway, thanks, if i don't find any other way to go, i'll do that.

Comment: This is a classical anti-pattern (but I suppose that there are exceptional cases where it is appropriate).

Comment: You're right, @JamesKanze, it's not nice at all. But it would work. Actually, I think [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11115578/1444073) is the best solution.